# Output different columns from 2 Select Statements

Tags: sql-server, row

I want to achieve something like;

eg.

```
ID  VALUE NAME
1   1234  COUNTER
2   1235  BAGGAGE
```

OUTPUT:

```
COUNTER BAGGAGE
1234    1235
```

Script:

```
SELECT ID, VALUE, NAME FROM table WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, VALUE, NAME FROM table WHERE ID = 2
```

RESULT:

```
ID  VALUE NAME
1   1234  COUNTER
2   1235  BAGGAGE
```

Is this a row to column approach?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table would just return the topmost record, I don't think this is somewhere near the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one standard solution

```
select max(case when name='counter' then value end) as counter,

       max(case when name='baggage' then value end) as baggage

from table
```

Answer (score 0):

try this::

```
select id,case when name='counter' then value else ' ' end as counter,

        case when name='baggage' then value else ' ' end as baggage

        from table
```

it outputs

```
  id  counter baggage
   1   1234
   2           1235
```

## [fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/99af6/2)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you use the query below. It's not very generic but may be sufficient in specific cases as is simple and easy to use.

```
select 
(select top 1 value from yourtable where name = 'counter') as counter,
(select top 1 value from yourtable where name = 'baggage') as baggage
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6def6/1)

Comment: this answers OP, but it violates the ID i think??

Comment: That's why I said it can be used but is not completely generic. If ID's are to be used for distinguishing between counter and baggage, they can be used in where clauses

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
   [ID] TINYINT
  ,[VALUE] SMALLINT
  ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID],[VALUE],[Name])
VALUES (1,1234,'COUNTER')
      ,(2,1235,'BAGGAGE')     

SELECT  [COUNTER]
       ,[BAGGAGE]
FROM 
(
    SELECT [VALUE]
          ,[Name]
    FROM @DataSource 
) AS DS
PIVOT
(
  MAX([VALUE]) FOR [Name] IN ([COUNTER], [BAGGAGE])
) AS PVT
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Check the [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13256).

Comment: Tho not implied, PIVOT is only available >= 2005 MS SQL versions, anyway, could have been the perfect solution.